ICSharpCode.Decompiler generates unwanted format
I'm new to using ICSharpCode.Decompiler. I'm just wondering if there is a DecompilerSettings setting that would remove all the unwanted formats? I tried decompiling a .net .dll file and this is how it generated it:
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<SetEditMode>d__37))]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public async global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IViewModel<Employee, IModelExtendedProperties>> SetEditMode(bool isEditMode)
{
    //IL_0007: Unknown result type (might be due to invalid IL or missing references)
    //IL_000c: Unknown result type (might be due to invalid IL or missing references)
    IsEditMode = isEditMode;
    await global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    return this;
}

I want to remove the annotations, the IL comment and also the global access modifier. I also want it to simplify the class names and avoid fully qualified class names. I want it to return methods like this:
public async Task<IViewModel<Employee, IModelExtendedProperties>> SetEditMode(bool isEditMode)
{
    
    IsEditMode = isEditMode;
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    return this;
}

Thanks in advance!
